# Make (`ocrmypdf`) command run in terminal AND include input name in that of the output

Tags: terminal, filenames, command, kubuntu, ocr

I have this line inside a Dolphin service-menu file that contains many other commands for PDF processing:

```
Exec=bash -c 'f="%u"; ocrmypdf "$f" "${f%.pdf}_ocr.pdf";'
```

It has the advantage of giving an output file of the form `MY_PDF_ocr.pdf`, thus keeping the name of the input file. But I would prefer to have the command running in terminal (`konsole`) so that I see the process.

For that, I can use the line:

```
Exec=konsole --noclose -e ocrmypdf "%u" ocr_en.pdf
```

but without the output keeping the name of the input.

A line like

```
Exec=konsole --noclose -e ocrmypdf "%u" "${%u}_ocr.pdf"
```

does nothing.

How to adjust the `ocrmypdf` so that the command is run in konsole and the output includes the name of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trials (and errors) a simple command like `ocrmypdf %u %u_ocr.pdf` will give an output file with an odd name (which includes the extension) of the form`INPUT.pdf_ocr.pdf`, and in the service menu:

```
Exec=konsole --noclose -e ocrmypdf %u %u_ocr.pdf
```

But a cleaner solution (inspired by what I could pick from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/z87dlh/comment/iycawja/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) (on proper format of a script) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1397336/925128) (on using `bash` with a such script in terminal) seems to be to create a separate script (e.g. `ocr_EN.sh`) for that OCR-command - of the form (for English):

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in "$@"
do
ocrmypdf "$f" "${f%.pdf}_ocr_EN.pdf"
done
```

Making it executable and then using the folowing command (here included in the line of a service menu file):

```
konsole --noclose -e bash /PATH/TO/ocr_EN.sh %f
```

which gives an output named `INPUT_ocr_EN.pdf` (without the extension appearing twice).